# Apt-get gives authentication warning every time

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

Whenever I apt-get something, it warns me that it is unauthenticated. This is a new problem; it started today. When I do `apt-key update`, it does nothing, and `apt-get update` gives me this error at the end of its output:

```
W: GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 30C0868B8020F06A Launchpad PPA for arand
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 5C92FC592AE51AB5 Launchpad PPA for consindo
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 3BDAAC08614C4B38 Launchpad otto06217
```

Does anyone know what's happening or how to fix it? I'm running ubuntu 12.04 (precise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ref: [ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1850930)

```
sudo apt-get clean
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Thanks. That seems to have done the trick. I'll accept the answer when I can

Comment: your welcome .. have a great day.